# JS module throwing error upon declaration

Tags: javascript, module, syntax

I have a webpage (.ejs) that calls a separate file to contain the necessary JS, as here:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  //stuff

  </head>
  <body>

  //stuff

  <script type="module" src="/public/js/p2p_logic.js"></script>                            
  
  </body>
</html>
```

With the corresponding JS as here:

```
//p2p_logic.js

addEventListener("load", connect);
addEventListener("load", initialize);

//stuff

function connect() {
console.log("FIRED CONNECT");    
}  //connect()

function initialize() {
console.log("FIRED INITIALIZE");
import WebRTCAdaptor from "./public/js/webrtc_adaptor.js"        
}  //initialize()
```

As can be seen, the JS file calls an 'import'.  I am having great difficulty getting this to be operative.  I have never used an 'import' within a JS script file (attached to an HTML/EJS page) before.  As written above, I am receiving this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  p2p_logic.js:27
```

I have also attempted to use 'curly' brackets, as here:

```
import {WebRTCAdaptor} from "./public/js/webrtc_adaptor.js"
```

However this seems to have no effect.  If I modify the JS file to 'import' on the initial line, as here:

```
//p2p_logic.js

import WebRTCAdaptor from "./public/js/webrtc_adaptor.js"   

addEventListener("load", connect);
addEventListener("load", initialize);

//stuff

function connect() {
console.log("FIRED CONNECT");    
}  //connect()

function initialize() {
console.log("FIRED INITIALIZE");
}  //initialize()
```

This throws a 404 error...which indicates a 'file not found'.  Specifically:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  webrtc_adaptor.js:1
```

That however is BS since the file is definitely in the './public/js' directory...the 'webrtc_adapter.js' file is in the same directory as the 'p2p_logic.js' file...but I am using an absolute path structure so I don't see how that would matter...?

I am beginning to think it is not possible to perform an 'import' of a file in this manner...I have never had an issue using an external JS file in conjunction with a HTML/EJS page before...however in those cases I never made usage of an 'import' statement.

Does anybody know if it is even possible to 'import' using an external JS file attached to a HTML/EJS page?

Comment: The `type="module"` attribute must be put on the `<script src="/public/js/p2p_logic2.js">` in your html file. Not on a `<script>` tag in the module code itself, which - as you can see - is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Your suggestion solved the syntax error involving the '<' bracket...however I am still having problems with the 'import' statement.  I have revised my code above to indicate what I have done and the issue I am encountering, thank you again.

Comment: "*the 'webrtc_adapter.js' file is in the same directory as the 'p2p_logic.js' file...but I am using an absolute path structure*" - no, `… from "./public/js/webrtc_adaptor.js"` is a relative path, not an absolute one. You'd want to use either `… from "/public/js/webrtc_adaptor.js"` or `… from "./webrtc_adaptor.js"`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply...yes see my post below where I had come to the same conclusion...and removed the 'period' in the path.  I appreciate your response.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You have script tags inside your .js file which is throwing an error because those are html and you can't have that in a JavaScript file. Remove those and you should be good

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your suggestion is how I would normally use an attached JS file (without the script tags) however my issue now is with the 'import' statement.  My code above has been revised to indicate the problem I am currently attempting to solve.  Thank you again for your input.

Comment: @Pangit You shouldn't revise your question to make it substantially different from before. You should ask another question.

Comment: OK, sorry I guess that is a good point.  I have it solved now anyway...my absolute path structure in the 'import' statement contained a period (".") in the path that should not have been there.  Thanks again to all that gave a response, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the 'import' problem now resolved...I had included a period (".") within the path that should not have been there...which is why I was seeing a 404 error being thrown.  The correct 'import' path should have been '/public/js/...' instead of './public/js/...'      Thanks again to those that responded.